# Split long text into groups of 255 characters using Excel (or other tool)

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel, is it possible to paste in a long text and have that split into subgroups of 255 characters each? It does not have to be split at a space or anything like that.

I tried to create a simple formula in Excel to get the first 255 characters of whatever is in column A, but not sure how to do this for the next sets of 255:

This is what I tried to get them from column A: `=LEFT(A1,255)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below formula in column B and drag it across:

`=MID($A1,255*(COLUMN()-2)+1,255)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the MID function to get a subset of the characters. You can put values for the sub section selection in the column headers, then refer to the values in the column headers in your MID function.